# How to make subchild affect parent state in react

Tags: reactjs

**Intro**

I'm just beggining with react, but I've got a project and I want to be able to affect parent state from a sub components (or however it's made).

The final result is to get a Contact list that can be edited on the fly.

**Problem:**

The easiest way to simplify the probably, that I have is probably by starting with the TodoApp (from React's site) that i've modified slightly. Instead of having a list item that is staticly constructed from the state

`ParentState ---> Content`

I want to be able to have something like this

`ParentState <--> ContentInput`

**State of my problem:**

The following code is where i'm stuck at. There is a comment down bellow. I would like to have that imput affect the TodoApp's State. Maybe I got it the wrong way, if so, what is the Right Way?

---

```
class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.showState = this.showState.bind(this);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <button onClick={this.showState}>Console log current state</button>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input ref="field" />
          <button>
            Add #{this.state.items.length + 1}
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!this.refs.field.value.length) {
      return;
    }
    const newItem = {
      text: this.refs.field.value,
      id: Date.now()
    };
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      items: prevState.items.concat(newItem)
    }));
  }
  showState() {
    console.log(this.state)
  }
}

class TodoList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.items.map(item => (
          // MAKE THAT INPUT CHANGE THE PARENT STATE
          <li key={item.id}><input type="text" defaultValue={item.text} /></li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

https://codepen.io/smdimagerie/pen/Zvdoaj?editors=0010

Answer (score 0):

If you really need direct communication between your parent and something deep in its render tree, you typically have a questionable design going on that should get cut up into single parent-child communication steps, so that you can ask at each step "is it really necessary that *this* specific child talks to *this* specific parent?".

That said, the obvious React way to do this is to pass down a function handler so that children can propagate data to a parent, which can then do "whatever is necessary":

```
class Parent extends Component {
  onChange(e) {
    ...
  }
  render() {
    return <Child onChange={e => this.onChange(e)}/>
  }
}
```

and then make the child call its `this.props.onChange(...)` when you need it to trigger functionality in the parent. If you need that to happen in the child's children, then you keep passing it down as far as necessary.

Alternatively, if you have a distance to cover, what you probably need instead is for "maybe some component, I don't know which, and I don't care" to do something based on an event getting generated. In this case, you can either use standard JS custom events dispatched on the document, or use a dipatching service like [flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) (which for small use cases is absurd overkill).